# Is there a way to use a loop to set choices in a list item in google forms scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a program I'm trying to make that takes the data in a spreadsheet and makes it into a google form and currently Im trying to make the 11 cells each populate one drop down list. there is the setChoices method and inside of it you createChoices but you cant have any other kind of code inside it to say make 11 Choices with a for loop each one being the next string in an array. If you can think of any other methods please let me know...

This is my code currently:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var names = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 200);

  var values = names.getValues();

  var number = 0

  var count = 0;

  var array = "'" + values[0] + "'";

  while (values[count] != "") {
    number++;
    count++;
    if (values[count] != "") {
      array = array + ", " + "'" + values[count] + "'";
    }
  }

  Logger.log(number);
  Logger.log(array);
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    Logger.log(values[i]);

  }

  var form = FormApp.create("Cleaners");

  var formid = form.getId();

  var dropdown1 = form.addListItem();

  dropdown1.setTitle("Choose a Cleaner:");

  dropdown1.setChoices([
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[0]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[1]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[2]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[3]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[4]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[5]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[6]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[7]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[8]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[9]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[10])
  ]);

}
```

When I make the dropdown I dont want to have to go in and change the amount of choices created if another name is added to the list.

Comment: it is better if you can show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Just a wild guess, that this has more to do with how your code is structured than a method to use.

Answer (score -1):

```
//try replacing your code
//this code requires you to access each value in the array "values" separately.
dropdown1.setTitle("Choose a Cleaner:");

dropdown1.setChoices([
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[0]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[1]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[2]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[3]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[4]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[5]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[6]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[7]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[8]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[9]),
    dropdown1.createChoice(values[10])
  ]);

// with the code
//this code allows you to access this entire array
//if values = ['cleaner1', 'cleaner2', 'cleaner3', ...]
//all of those values would be accessed by drowdown1.setChoiceValues(values);
//setChoiceValues(values); is doing this .setChoiceValues(['cleaner1', 'cleaner2', 'cleaner3', ...]);
//where values is an array
dropdown1.setTitle("Choose a Cleaner:")
         .setChoiceValues(values);
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score -1):

recently I had the same issue and finally i have succeed to do it with a string array:

```
var item = newForm.addListItem();
 var arr = [];

 item.setTitle('Please choose somthing');

   for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) { 
     arr.push(y);
 }

 item.setChoiceValues(arr);
```

good luck !

Answer (score -1):

I found something that will put array items as pickable answers (will also put empty values)
`.setChoiceValues();`

For example:

`FormApp.openById(FormID).addListItem().setChoiceValues(ArrayName);`